# Populating listview web control from a datareader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

This is my first time trying to use listviews and I've spent the better part of a day beating my head against a wall trying to make it work. I've created a listview that I'm trying to populate with data from an Oracle DB. I'm trying to use a datareader to populate the listview but I'm having a hard time making it work. There is a lot out there on accomplishing this for the listview form control but not much for the web control. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The furthest I've been able to get is with this:

```
While reader.Read

   Dim obj As New ListViewDataItem((reader(0)), (reader(1)))
   lsvGeneratedForms.Items.Add(obj)

End While
```

But this only allows me to read 2 objects (I need to pull in 4) and I run into a type conversion error as my DB contains only string & date datatypes.

Markup for listview:

```
<div class="GeneratedFormsDivStyle" style="height:300px; overflow:scroll">
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lsvGeneratedForms">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="tblFormList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tr style="background-color:#ccdaeb">
               <th align="left">
               <asp:Label ID="hdrAgreeNo" runat="server" Text="Agreement No"/>    </th>
               <th align="left">
               <asp:Label ID="hdrGenDate" runat="server" Text="Date Generated"/></th>
               <th align="left">
               <asp:Label ID="hdrLEAcct" runat="server" Text="Legal Entity Account"/></th>
               <th align="left">
               <asp:Label ID="hdrStatus" runat="server" Text="Status"/></th>
           </tr>
           <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAgreeNo"><%#Eval("AGREEMENT_NUM")%></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGenDate"><%#Eval("GEN_DATE")%></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLEAcct"><%#Eval("LE_ACCOUNT")%></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"><%#Eval("STATUS")%></asp:Label></td>                    
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Comment: `ListView` is a databound control.  The concept is that each "item" corresponds to an item in the bound datasource.  That "item" can have multiple properties (fields).  It looks like you're trying to set all the "Item" properties in the code behind.  I would suggest changing your approach - create a collection of the "Items" from your database and bind that collection to the `ListView`.  E.g., create a class that has properties that match the names in your databinding, build a `List<T>` of that class and bind the list to the control.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my example, create a class:

```
Public Class MyItem

    Public Property AGREEMENT_NUM As String
    Public Property GEN_DATE As String
    Public Property LE_ACCOUNT As String
    Public Property STATUS As String
End Class
```

This matches the fields you are populating in the `<ItemTemplate>`.

Next, you could map the results from the reader to the class:

```
Dim myItems As List(Of MyDataItem) = New List(Of MyDataItem)()

While (reader.Read())
    Dim newItem As New MyDataItem With { .AGREEMENT_NUM = reader(0).ToString(), .GEN_DATE = reader(1).ToString(), .LE_ACCOUNT = reader(2).ToString(), .STATUS = reader(2).ToString() }
    myItems.Add(newItem)
End While
```

Then you can bind the list:

```
MyListView.DataSource = myItems
MyListView.DataBind()
```

The above code is an example - you will need to adjust it accordingly for your code.  The important thing is to ensure that the collection of objects you are binding has the corresponding field names used in the markup.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm having some trouble with the syntax for the following line: 

Dim newItem As ListViewDataItem With { .AGREEMENT_NUM = reader(0).ToString(), .GEN_DATE = reader(1).ToString(), .LE_ACCOUNT = reader(2).ToString(), .STATUS = reader(3).ToString()}

I'm getting and 'End of Statement Expected' error...what do I have off?

Comment: @StephenT - If `ListViewDataItem` is from `System.Web.UI.Controls`, you can't do what you're trying to do as those properties won't be understood by the compiler.  You need to use a custom class as I gave in my example.  Do note that I had a typo in my example (I don't do VB.NET very often) - it should be `Dim newItem As New MyDataItem....` - it was missing the `New` keyword.